# Lifetime of temporary objects passed to a member storing a constant reference

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose I have an object Obj and a Set s. The Set is collecting const Obj& references in an array. How long will the actual Obj's be available:

```
{
    Set s;
    s.add(Obj(...));
    s.add(Obj(...));

    s.doWhateverWithTheObjs();

}
// after this it's guaranteed to not work anymore, if s was on the heap. Obj's will die with stack
```

I have not implemented that yet as I first want to confirm that this is actually going to work.

I know it won't work when the Set is on the heap and it's lifetime is longer then the lifetime of the caller (I made brackets to illustrate this).

What I don't know is whether the last method has still read access to the objects? Storing actual object by value in the Set won't work, because Obj is polymorph. If possible, I don't want to use pointers for usability reasons.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `add`? If it doesn't do anything weird, then this should be okay.

Comment: You *can't* have an array of references. Please show us more details, like the `add` function, and how and where it stores data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I don't know is whether the last method has still read access to the objects?

The standard defines two cases in which the lifetime of a temporary is extended, at §12.2/4:

> The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array. If the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.

which is supposed to allow initializations of arrays. The second, which is of more concern is connected to *references* (at §12.2/5):

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.118 The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:

As you can see, if a temporary object is bounded to a reference, the lifetime of the object extends to that of the reference. After the "except:" it is listed:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

This basically says, that no matter how you define the function body of `add`, if `add`'s signature is `T add(const Obj&)` (with any `T`), the temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the call to that function. This means that in:

```
s.add(Obj(...));
```

The temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the function execution.

Therefore, for the above reasons: no. It won't still have read access to the object. You'll have a reference to a deallocated object.

---

> Storing actual object by value in the Set won't work, because Obj is polymorph.

You can have a polymorphic behavior and still hold the objects. You can use for example an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::unique_ptr<Obj>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The creation of a new object will happen like this:

```
vector.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Obj>(new Derived()));
```

and you will have a polymorphic vector that also store the values.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're inside the function, unless you replicate the object inside `s.add` (which, according to your question, you don't (Set is collecting const Obj& references in an array).

Second thought, not even during the function, since each `Obj` instance is allocated on the stack of the function **only temporarily**, during the call to `s.add(Obj(...));`.

In other words, don't do it this way (you must replicate the object inside `s.add`).

**Supplemental:**

There is nothing wrong with having const Obj& references in an array, but you gotta have the actual instances allocated somewhere, whether it's on the heap, or in the data-section (as global variables)... or on the stack of the calling function (as local variables) if you're not using them outside the function.